# Add prefix to each file name in cmd and list them

Tags: cmd

Below command adds prefix to all files and lists them in `out.txt`. But

1. it also lists the folder names
2. and adds file path which I don't want.

Is it possible the desired output in cmd itself? Any help will be appreciated.

**Command:**

```
    for /f %f in ('dir /b /s *.*') do echo dt obsolete %f >> out.txt
```

**Current output:**

```
dt obsolete D:\workdir\src1\drafttest2\python 
dt obsolete D:\workdir\src1\drafttest2\draftingdimension\ind 
dt obsolete D:\workdir\src1\drafttest2\draftingdimension\ind\GB_005.seq 
dt obsolete D:\workdir\src1\drafttest2\draftingdimension\ind\GB_005_py.py
```

**Desired output:**

```
dt obsolete GB_005.seq 
dt obsolete GB_005_py.py
```

Comment: What have you tried? this isn't a give me the code service! I would suggest that you would be more likely to need this type of thing from a [tag:batch-file], not for [tag:cmd], please be clear about which you're needing this for when you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55021089/edit), to provide a [mcve] of the code you've written which actually attempt the task you've laid out, and according to the information you should have gleaned from taking the [tour] and reading [ask].

Comment: so I would suggest you start off by reading some help, open `cmd` and specifically read `for /?`

Comment: From the `cmd.exe` prompt, you can use `(For /R "D:\workdir\src1\drafttest2" %A In (*)Do @Echo dt obsolete %~nxA)>"out.txt"` where the first set of doublequotes contains your base directory, _(can be omitted if your current directory is the base directory)_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a go at this from cmdline:

```
for /f %f in ('dir /b /s *.*') do echo dt "obsolete_%~nxf">>out.txt
```

or if you want to include the path:

```
for /f %f in ('dir /b /s *.*') do echo dt "%~dpfobsolete_%~nxf">>out.txt
```

Not sure if you plan to do this for files only or files and folders, but if files only, then:

```
for /f %f in ('dir /b /s /a-d *.*') do echo dt "%~dpfobsolete_%~nxf">>out.txt
```

To run the above from batch file, you need to double up on all the `%`

As mentioned in my comment as well, from cmd.exe run `for /?` to see all the help you need on variable expansion.

Comment: `for /f %f in ('dir /b /s /a-d *.*') do echo dt obsolete %~nxf>>out.txt` This is command I wanted. Can I get output on cmd itself instead of in text file?

Comment: @Experimenter, yes; remove the `>>out.txt`, _(redirection to a text file)_, `For /R %A In (*)Do @Echo dt obsolete %~nxA`

Comment: I could see that but not useful, as I can't copy all output. Actually output is commands and I want to run them in new cmd.

Comment: Then do not echo it. do the actual command instead of echo. i.e let's say you want to rename them, then instead of `echo`, do `ren "%~nxf" "obsolete %~nxf"`

Comment: …that would need to be `ren "%f" "obsolete %~nxf"` though!